# "Enter Parameter Value" Dialogue

Tags: sql, ms-access

I get the "Enter Parameter Value" popup when I run the below (asking for November.MPXN)

```
UPDATE Master SET [MPXN] = November.MPXN, [Clarification Text] = November.[Clarification Text]
WHERE (EXISTS(SELECT 1  FROM November AS November
    WHERE [November.Case] = [Master.Case]));
```

I assume it isn't pulling the date for November.MPXN for some reason, I would have though it's pretty obvious that it's in the November table but must be something wrong with the query, can anyone help me please?

Comment: My guess would be MPXN or Clarification Text has a `&` value in it part of the string.  Pretty sure & is used by Access as an escape character for user input.  When encountered, MsAccess will prompt for a value.  To correct, I believe you would need to use replace to double them up for it to work. or use paramaterized query instead.

Comment: Thanks but no, MPXN is a double and the Clarification Text is all text with no & in there.

Comment: Perhaps: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Why-does-Access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-a7344543-e758-4785-8433-420eb0f0b48e

Comment: Thanks xQbert, that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got an answer already but `November` is not in the same scope as the `Update` part of the query. It is nested inside your `exists` statement. You need a join to bring the `November` data in with the `Master` data.

```
UPDATE Master M
INNER JOIN November N
On N.[November.Case] = M.[Master.Case]
SET [MPXN] = November.MPXN
, [Clarification Text] = November.[Clarification Text]
```

I bet you were using `Exists` though because the records in Master and `November` are not 1 to 1 in which case you'll need to have some way to narrowing it down.